# My element dissapeared on portrait tablet screen

Tags: html, css

I coded a responsive website, all the screen are seem to be perfect but in the tablet mode (portrait). My footer is not showing up on this screen only. I added 2 media query on CSS but it doesn't work by the way.

Here's my footer code and CSS code :

```css
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #home {
    height: 125vh;
  }
  .ul--tool {
    columns: 4;
    -webkit-columns: 4;
    -moz-columns: 4;
  }
  .ul--program {
    columns: 4;
    -webkit-columns: 4;
    -moz-columns: 4;
  }
  .service-thumb2 {
    margin-bottom: 22px;
  }
}

@media screen and (orientation: landscape) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #home {
    height: 125vh;
  }
  .ul--tool {
    columns: 4;
    -webkit-columns: 4;
    -moz-columns: 4;
  }
  .ul--program {
    columns: 4;
    -webkit-columns: 4;
    -moz-columns: 4;
  }
  .service-thumb2 {
    margin-bottom: 22px;
  }
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <br>
      <div class="wow fadeInUp col-md-12 col-sm-12" data-wow-delay="0.8s">
        <p class="white-color">Copyright &copy; 2021 <strong>Khoa Nguyễn</strong> | Powered by <strong>Hostinger</strong></p>
        <div class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
          <ul class="social-icon">
            <li>
              <a data-wow-delay="0.5s" href="https://facebook.com/rogkhoa" target="_blank" class="fa fa-facebook wow fadeInUp"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a data-wow-delay="0.65s" href="https://instagram.com/_youngboiluytinh_" target="_blank" class="fa fa-instagram wow fadeInUp"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a data-wow-delay="0.75s" href="https://www.behance.net/rogkhoa" target="_blank" class="fa fa-behance wow fadeInUp"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a data-wow-delay="0.85s" href="https://github.com/ROGKhoa" target="_blank" class="fa fa-github wow fadeInUp"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a data-wow-delay="0.95s" href="https://linktr.ee/khoanguyn" target="_blank" class="fa fa-link wow fadeInUp"></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the width of your tablet is not more then 1024px? You media query will apply only if the screen is less then 1024px;
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

Comment: @ZsoltBalogh morelikely you should ask him if he is aware of the difference between hardware pixel (physical pixel) and software pixel (css pixel). I'm not aware of any consumer tablet that has a width of more then 1024 css-px atm.

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove "overflow: hidden;" that has impact on footer in your css. I see you're using WOW.js, it works wrong with overflow hidden. I was able to reproduce it with said css rule. Also footer has unclosed div.